# Verify if a private key needs a passphrase or not

Tags: python, ssl, python-ssl

I want to write a piece of code which will load a certificate and its key and use them to set up HTTPS.
I encountered the problem of an RSA key which requires a passphrase: if the key requires a passphrase and I don't pass it to the `password` argument of [ssl.load_certs_chain](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ssl.html#ssl.SSLContext.load_cert_chain), the code will hang waiting for user to prompt the passphrase.

What I would like to do instead is to either fail when the code tries to load the key *or* detect from the key if it needs a passphrase or not.

I tried to put a default value `"-"` to `password` paramter of `ssl.load_cert_chain` in order to get an error of "wrong password" if the key required a passphrase, but I only get this output

```
ssl.SSLError: [SSL] PEM lib (_ssl.c:4065)
```

which is meaningless. There is no details about the exception

Answer (score 1):

From the docs you linked:

> The password argument may be a function to call to get the password for decrypting the private key. It will only be called if the private key is encrypted and a password is necessary. It will be called with no arguments, and it should return a string, bytes, or bytearray. If the return value is a string it will be encoded as UTF-8 before using it to decrypt the key. Alternatively a string, bytes, or bytearray value may be supplied directly as the password argument. **It will be ignored if the private key is not encrypted and no password is needed.**
>
> If the password argument is not specified and a password is required, OpenSSL’s built-in password prompting mechanism will be used to interactively prompt the user for a password.

You could pass a function of your own that raises a custom exception if the password fails.

Comment: Wow. I don't know how did I missed that. Thanks. I'll try that and let you know

Comment: Thanks @Daviid. This fixed the issue.

Comment: I have another question:
is there a way to also trap the case when the password is wrong?
This is the output I get RN if it's wrong: `ssl.SSLError: [SSL] PEM lib (_ssl.c:4065)`. Same unknown error